# Define an XML schema from a txt file With Python script and store it in a single XML file

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to write an xml schema using python from a .txt file. I tried the following code but it didn't read the values in lines of the text.

```
     The data is like:
      #  File format is Team:Player:Salary:Position
      New York Yankees :"Acevedo Juan"  :   900000: Pitcher
      New York Yankees :"Anderson Jason":   300000: Pitcher 
      ............
```

and the code:

```
    import re
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    root = ET.Element('root')
    root.text = '\n'    # newline before the celldata element
    f = open("C:/baseball.txt")
    lines = f.readlines()
       for l in lines:
           elems = l.split(":")
      if len(elems) == 4:
           elems = map(lambda x: x.strip(), elems)
           playerdata = ET.SubElement(root, "playerdata")
           playerdata.text = '\n'
           playerdata.tail = '\n\n'
           team = ET.SubElement(playerdata, "team")
           player = ET.SubElement(playerdata, "player")
           salary = ET.SubElement(playerdata, "salary")
           position = ET.SubElement(playerdata, "position")
      ET.dump(root)
      tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
      tree.write("test1.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

The output I got looks like this:

```
     <root>
     <playerdata>
     <team /><player /><salary /><position /></playerdata>

     <playerdata>
     <team /><player /><salary /><position /></playerdata>

     <playerdata>
     <team /><player /><salary /><position /></playerdata>
     .
     .
     .
     <playerdata>
     <team /><player /><salary /><position /></playerdata>

     </root>
```

Comment: Are you sure your indentation is correct?  I don't see how you get this output with this code.  The actual problem is almost certainly that you never set the `text` value for the subelements you create.

Comment: Yes it's correct. And can you please help me on how to create an xml with pithon from txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few changes, plus the fix.  The changes are:

1. Using a context manager to ensure the input file gets closed
   correctly.
2. Using the fact that iterating a file yields each line in
   turn (rather than `f.readlines()`).
3. Combining the splitting and stripping of the parts of the line into one statement.

The fix is to set the `text` value for the subelements just after they are created.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element('root')
root.text = '\n'    # newline before the celldata element
with open("C:/baseball.txt") as f:
   for l in f:
       elems = [ x.strip() for x in l.split(":") ]
       if len(elems) == 4:
           playerdata = ET.SubElement(root, "playerdata")
           playerdata.text = '\n'
           playerdata.tail = '\n\n'
           team = ET.SubElement(playerdata, "team")
           team.text = elems[0]
           player = ET.SubElement(playerdata, "player")
           player.text = elems[1]
           salary = ET.SubElement(playerdata, "salary")
           salary.text = elems[2]
           position = ET.SubElement(playerdata, "position")
           position.text = elems[3]

  ET.dump(root)
  tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
  tree.write("test1.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```