# Writing strings to xml in python

Tags: xml, python-3.x

So am still learning how to use xml.etree.ElementTree to create xml document. I would like to write sentences of strings to xml file.

Here is my code:

```
   import sys
   import os
   import re
   import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

   input_f = "test.txt"
   output_f = "results.txt"
   lines = open(input_f, "r").readlines()
   sentences = [x.strip() for x in ' '.join(lines).replace("\n","").split(".")]

    with open(output_f,"w") as f:
        for sentence in sentences:
            if sentence != "":
               f.write("%s\n\n" % sentence)

    xml_list = []

    #convert sentences to xml    
    for line in output_f:
        event_descri = ET.fromstring(line, parser=None)
        xml_list.append(event_descri)

    # writes to xml file
    with open("chronology.xml", "w") as f:
      f.write(ET.tostring(xml_list))
```

This is my error:

```
    File "C:\Python34\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1326, in XML
    return parser.close()
    File "<string>", line None
    xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
```

What is happening here? Can anyone help?

Comment: For a start, `output_f` is the name of a file (results.txt), not the contents of the file.  This means that `for line in output_f:` iterates over the characters in the name, not the lines in the file.  You also need to create some elements, not just accumulate text (I'm assuming that there are not xml tags in the input file).

Comment: I have only managed to create an xml file separate. When I try to incoporate it into my code I get confused because I dont seem  to understand how to parse the strings from the textfile to the element.

Comment: You can see an example of how to do this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224221/define-an-xml-schema-from-a-txt-file-with-python-script-and-store-it-in-a-single/45228047#45228047